# What pattern to use when a component only needs to dispatch an action creator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component that doesn't need to have access to the global state, but does need to dispatch an action creator.

It seems there are two alternatives:

- using react-redux connect() and passing the global state via `mapStateToProps` and passing my action creator via `mapDispatchToProps` - from what I can make out, passing the global state like this is not a good idea though
- not using react-redux connect() and using this.props.dispatch instead

Are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass `null`, instead of `mapStateToProps` function.

There are ways to achieve the goal:

1.**Inject just `dispatch` function and don't listen to `store`**

```
export default connect()(Component);
```

then in component

```
this.props.dispatch(actionCreator());
```

---

2.**Inject `actions creators` and don't listen to `store`**

```
import * as actionCreators from './actionCreators'

export default connect(null, actionCreators)(Component);
```

then in component

```
this.props.actionCreator();
```

---

BTW, you should never pass the global state.  It kills any performance optimizations because Component will rerender after every action.